# Adding long press gesture recognizer to UITextView

Tags: swift, uitextview

I'm trying to let the user move a text view around the screen as he presses down on it. The issue I'm getting is my gesture recognizer isn't getting called and instead the text is being selected when I press down on it. How can I disable this? I can't just disable user interaction because a tap should still let the user edit the text. My code is below

```
let longPressRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "longPressed:")
text.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRecognizer)

func longPressed(sender : UITextView) {
        println("long press")
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12296262/uitextview-gesture-tap-recognizer-not-working-after-text-begins-to-edit ?

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this tiny piece of code. Sometimes it makes magic happen ;)

```
text.userInteractionEnabled = true
```